# How to prevent bursting from cheese stuffed beef patties?

Tags: cheese, hamburgers

I am trying to perfect the cheese burger, and an important part for me is the cheese stuffed patty.

I am trying to find a way to prevent the cheese from bursting out? Is there a type of cheese I can use, or a method of compacting the beef? Should I be encasing the cheese in another layer first?

Comment: Do you press the burger at all during cooking?

Comment: Nope, just stick them under the grill

Comment: If you're forming the beef pretty tightly, try being a bit more loose about it?

Answer (score 4):

Most cheeses are going to want to melt and ooze out unless they are very hard and stringy cheeses. A hard mozzarella sliced along the strings may work, but I'd try halloumi above all. You can fry halloumi on a pan and it will brown and form a crust, so it is perfect to stuff in a burger patty.

Comment: Good suggestion, but halloumi isn't much of a 'burger cheese'. It's not very cheesy tasting, it's just salty.

Comment: It wouldn't be my first choice either, however if the requirement is that all the cheese stays in the burger you have to compromise. Personally I would slap a slice of cheddar on top and revel in it oozing down the sides. OK, now I'm hungry, and I won't be able to concentrate for thinking about juicy burgers! Thanks a bunch @ElendilTheTall. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Use less cheese. Think of a normal cheeseburger - a relatively thin slice of cheese makes its presence known. Also, use fine shreds or small crumbles.

2) Cook lower and slower - part of the problem may come from the cheese losing liquid and giving off steam. Too much at once, and it will burst the pocket.